# how do I drill down and get the src and href of a div using beautifulsoup4

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to drill down and get the src and href of a div using beautifulsoup4. I have read the docs watched tutorials and searched stack for posts and have not found one. heres the html code

```
<div class="thumbnail thumb">
     <h6 id="date">May 2, 2016</h6>
         <img src="http://www.viveca.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/End_of_the_Line025.jpg" class="img-responsive post">

                <div style="border-bottom: thin solid lightslategray; padding-bottom: 15px;"></div>

                <div class="caption" id="cap">
                    <a href="/blog/just-filler/">
                        <h5 class="post-title" id="title">just filler</h5>
                    </a>

                    <p>
                        <a href="/blog/36/delete/" class="btn" role="button">delete</a>
                        <a href="/blog/just-filler/edit/" class="btn" role="button">edit</a>
                    </p>

                </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this

```
entries = [{'text': div.text,
          'href': div.get('div', {'class', 'thumbnail'}).a,
          'src': div.get('src')
          } for div in divs]
```

but it does not work

I'm usint this with in my django app. What's the correct syntax to scrape the href and the src. the text works just not the src and href.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup might have a smarter, built-in way of doing it but this seems to work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """
<div class="thumbnail thumb">
     <h6 id="date">May 2, 2016</h6>
         <img src="http://www.viveca.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/End_of_the_Line025.jpg" class="img-responsive post">

                <div style="border-bottom: thin solid lightslategray; padding-bottom: 15px;"></div>

                <div class="caption" id="cap">
                    <a href="/blog/just-filler/">
                        <h5 class="post-title" id="title">just filler</h5>
                    </a>

                    <p>
                        <a href="/blog/36/delete/" class="btn" role="button">delete</a>
                        <a href="/blog/just-filler/edit/" class="btn" role="button">edit</a>
                    </p>

                </div>
</div>
"""

parsed = soup(html, "html.parser")

divs = parsed.find_all("div")

entries = [{'text': div.text,
            'src' : map(lambda img : img.get("src"), div.find_all('img')),
            'href': map(lambda a : a.get("href"), div.find_all('a'))
          } for div in divs if "thumbnail" in div.get("class", [])]

print entries
```

Output:

```
[{'text': u'\nMay 2, 2016\n\n\n\n\njust filler\n\n\ndelete\nedit\n\n\n', 'href': [u'/blog/just-filler/', u'/blog/36/delete/', u'/blog/just-filler/edit/'], 'src': [u'http://www.viveca.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/End_of_the_Line025.jpg']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked
in my views

```
entries = [{'text': div.text,
          'href': div.find('a').get('href'),
          'src': div.find('img').get('src')
          } for div in divs]
```

and in my template

```
{% for e in entries %}
    <a href="{{url}}{{ e.href }}" class="thumbnail">{{ e.text }}</a><br>
{{e.href}}<br>
```